# Question about generating "difference images"

Tags: python, image-processing, pixel

I'm trying to generate some informative images from .avi video files. I was wondering if there was a way to take two images in greyscale - and generate an image that for every pixel value is the difference of pixel values in the two selected images. I.e. if a pixel in the first image is 2% (black (0%) and white (100%)) and the last image at the same pixel has 25% the generated image at this pixel will be 23%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with python, it is pretty straight forward.

```
import numpy as np
img1 = #first grayscale image
img2 = #second grayscale image

diff = np.abs(img1.astype(np.uint) - img2.astype(np.uint)).astype(np.uint8)
#diff has the required difference data
#here is the code to save an image (simply chage the extension at "filename.***" to save in the required format)
cv2.imwrite("filename.jpg",diff)
```

Comment: Heres my code so far:  `import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread('img1.jpg)'
img2 = cv2.imread('img2.jpg')

diff = np.abs(img1.astype(np.uint) - img2.astype(np.uint)).astype(np.uint8)
print(diff)`                                                                                                                                     However even though the images are distinct I get the following output : `[[[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
...

Comment: Ideally, I would like diff to be a .jpg image and not an array, how do I do this conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that ended up working:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img1 = cv2.imread('img1.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('img2.jpg')

diff = np.abs(img1.astype(np.uint) - img2.astype(np.uint)).astype(np.uint8)

img = Image.fromarray(diff)
img.save("diff.png")
```